# edit google sheet cells not as the logged user with WebApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

1. There is a sheet that is shared with writing permissions to users `A` and `B`.
2. Column `X` is protected and can be edited only by user `A`.
3. User `B` should use a script with user `A` permissions to edit column `X`.

From reading the various documentation (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization), I understand that there are two ways to run a script on a google sheet as a different user.

1. Using the python api (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python). The disadvantages: either launches from the cmdline, or Google's App Engine which is not free.
2. Using a WebApp. My problem with that solution, and perhaps this is what I am missing, is how to edit a cell with the `doGet` and `doPost`. All the examples that I saw were using the google script to edit the cells, which slammed me back to the permissions issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution: User A should deploy the web app with settings "execute as me [that is, A]", and choose access level as "anyone" [so that user B can access] or "anyone,  even anonymous" to save user B an extra step and allow them to access the app programmatically. To prevent users other than B from editing, A gives B an access token, which B uses in their GET or POST requests. For example: user B accesses the app via GET request to `https://..../exec?key=mykey`, and the app has code like this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.key == "mykey") {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheet Id"); // can't use getActiveSpreadsheet in doGet/doPost
    // do something with the spreadsheet
  }
}
```

Documentation: [doGet/doPost event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters).

Comment: This is a great answer, but there is one issue left: one cannot use a fetch call on that link from within the google script, if the WebApp is not shared with the entire world. It makes some sense, as the GET is not from within my domain - but hi google - you are my domain..

Comment: do you think that is a bug?

Comment: Then open to "anyone, even anonymous". The web app won't do anything with requests unless they contain a valid key parameter. In fact, I'm running an app like this right now, and have been for 1.5 years.